# How to extract a specific part of a string

Tags: javascript

I have this bunch of code in a variable as string:

```
.... = 40; var posY = 40; MAX_727.moveTo(posX, posY); } MAX_727.location='http://one.cam4ads.com/www/delivery/ac.php?bannerid=727&zoneid=19&target=_blank&withtext=0&source=&timeout=0&ct0='; MAX_727.blur(); window.focus...
```

(I added dots at the begining and end to make it easier to read)

This code (which is being manipulated as string) contains a variable value, `MAX_727.location`.

How can I extract the value of that specific variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
var value = /MAX_727\.location=\'([^\']*)/.exec(s)[1];
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rsqMf/)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you're not sure the string contains what you're looking for, you should check the length of the array returned by the `exec` function.

Answer (score 0):

If MAX_727.location is the only part of the string that is in single quote marks, you can split the string into an array containing [*before text*,*text in quotes*,*after text*]:

```
var codeString = "your String goes here";
var codeArray = codeString.split("'"); //Split the String at every ' mark, and add it to an array
var location = codeArray[1]; //Get the second value in the array, or the part of the String that was in quotes.
```